# Alternate row colors with split cells

Tags: excel

I am trying to alternate row colors within a workbook that also contains split cells. I have successfully managed to alternate the row colors but am getting stuck on the split cells.

An example of the spread sheet:

[Example Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks44T.png)

I have used the following formula to generate this `=MOD(ROW()-2,4)>=3` but I can't get the leaf cells to use the correct formatting. What I would like is for the leaf cells to be displayed like so:

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVeAZ.png)

Comment: Your two examples don't show the same data. Can you show how you want the wrong colored cells to be formatted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the answer was around the code in C#. I used the following formulas from Excel =MOD(ROW()-1,4)>=2 and MOD(ROW(),2)=1

In C# I had to create 2 rules

```
xl.FormatCondition format = range.Rows.FormatConditions.Add(xl.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, xl.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "=MOD(ROW()-1,4)>=2");
xl.FormatCondition test = range.Rows.FormatConditions.Add(xl.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, xl.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlLess, "MOD(ROW(),2)=1");
```

This then provided the correct outcome for me.